# How do I get Make to acknowledge two intermediate dependencies from one recipe?

Tags: make, gnu-make

I am converting `.sup` files to `.ass` files using the following recipes:

```
%.idx %.sub: %.sup
    bdsup2subpp --language en -o $*.sub $<

%.srt: %.sub
    vobsub2srt $*

%.ass: %.srt
    ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -nostdin -i $< $@
```

Make will delete all the intermediate `.sub` and `.srt` files, but it does not seem to notice the `.idx` files. Adding the `%.idx` dependency to the `vobsub2srt` recipe will cause it to delete either the `.idx` or `.sub` files depending on which came first, but never both.

Is there a way to get make to recognise that both intermediates were generated from this single pattern rule, and thus delete them once everything is made?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the best way, but

```
%.idx: %sup
  bdsup2subpp --language en -o $*.sub $<

%.sub: %.idx
  true
```

It has some problems. It may not try to generate the `%.sub`, I originally had it the other way around

```
%.sub: %sup
  bdsup2subpp --language en -o $@ $<

%.idx: %.sub
  true
```

But realised that it would not trigger the 2nd rule.